# Call firebase only once instead of 50 times to get posts data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to get data from 2 json files in firebase, so I do this:

```
feedRef = firebase.database().ref().child('feed').child(id).limitToLast(50);
feedRef.once('value', async function(snapshot) {

    snapshot.forEach((subChild) => {
    var value = subChild.val();

    value = subChild.key;   // maybe get a array of values?             

    var post = firebase.database().ref('/posts/' + value).orderByKey(); // inside loop 50 times
```

I'd like to know if there is a way that I can get all data keys I need and select from `posts` all the value only once instead of put it inside loop running 50 times as I'm doing...

Thanks a lot.

---

edit:

```
posts
  |
  --- key (eg. 123)
       |
       --- img
       |
       --- text
       |
       --- user

feed
  |
  --- user_uid key
           |
           --- post id reference (eg. 123)
                  |
                  --- postID: 123
```

Comment: Please post your database structure as well.

Comment: @GrahamD I edit my question.

Comment: You refer to a child `user-posts` but I don't see it there?

Comment: @GrahamD sorry, it is `feed`, not user-posts anymore. I changed the name of the json and forget to change here.

Comment: Just to confirm I understand what you are trying to achieve: You want to retrieve the last 50 posts for a specific user id?

Comment: Or all the posts of the last 50 users, not sure what that would mean.

Comment: @GrahamD I get all the post ids from an user (auth id) `feed` and "join" `post` to get the complete post data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214236/discussion-between-grahamd-and-rick-joe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per our discussion in chat:

Ideally you need to avoid the 50-500+ database calls within the loop as this will cause performance issues, I'm sure. To avoid such 'joins' in FB RTDB usually involves creating additional node(s) and/or synthesizing compound keys so that you can read what you want with one call or monitor it with one listener.

In your project I would look to create a third node called eg. `postsFollowed` that has a key of `user_uid` and lists all the posts, and their data, that the user is following. The key used for the posts could be the unique one generated by FB, in which case they are in chronological order, or one you allocate yourself ie. the key used in `feeds`, which could itself be the FB generated one.

You can then read this node for a specific `user_id`, child `postId`, orderbykey, limit to last 50 (or whatever) and get everything you need in one call.

This will mean a lot of data duplication (you need to think about the magnitude of this given that multiple people will, I assume, be following the same post) so you need to ensure that the keys and data you store are as compact as possible. Do the math on storage.

Given this structure and data duplicated across nodes, in order to ensure data integrity you need to do 'atomic writes' where you set or update the 'post' on all the relevant nodes in one database operation that either all succeeds or all fails.

Hope this helps and works out for you.